# Color profile change seems to have no effect

Tags: linux, colors, monitors, color-management

I'm using a machine with both, Windows (10) and Linux Mint + Unity installed. Colors on Linux look quite strange and poorly calibrated, but everything looks fine on Windows.

I was assuming that my problem might be related to the screen color profile in use, so I imported ICC profiles from Windows following this answer. However, when I go to settings and switch between color profiles for my monitor, I literally see no difference at all. The only profile causing a visual change is the built-in one called "Blue", which I assume is for testing purposes.

What's going on here; i.e. are the profiles not actually applied or is it possible that those profiles from Windows don't work on Linux for some reason?